# How to avoid calling pytest_generate_tests multiple times

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a test suite, wherein

- Master class Regression holds generic test functions, which are inherited by child classes
- I am dynamically parameterizing the test variables during initialization using pytest_generate_tests hook.
- The test initialization depends on the child class which is being run
  Eg. Test_window will have diff initialization
  Test_door will have diff initialization

My problem is:

- For both the test cases I use same parameter
- So the pytest_generate_tests hook gets called 2 times to generate the same test data ( i guess, couldn't find it in docs !!!)
- Is there a better way of implementing this scenario to avoid this overhead of calling the pytest_generate_tests  2 times.

**Parent Class :**

```
class Regression:

def test_work(self, data):
    test_func1_call_using data(data)


def test_agg(self, data):
    test_func2_call_using data(data)
```

**Test Class 1 inherting regression :**

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('generic_test_setup')
class Test_window(Regression):
   dummy_var=0
```

**Test Class 2 inherting regression :**

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('generic_test_setup')
class Test_door(Regression):
   dummy_var=0
```

**conftest.py :**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def generic_test_setup(request, env):
   // do setup 

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    class_name = metafunc.cls.__name__.split('_')[1]
    
    logging.info(f"Collection Phase :: Initializing test_data for {class_name} !!!")

    // Initialize the test data based on the calling class 
    test_data = //generated dictionary value with ids and test data

    id_entity = [d['entity'] for d in test_data]
    if "data" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("data", test_data, ids=id_entity )
    
@pytest.fixture
def data(request):
    return request.param
```

Comment: The parameter is not relevant here, those are still two different tests.

Comment: If the test data creation is really that expansive, you can cache it (for example in a dictionary). Apart from that, this works as expected, `pytest_generate_tests` is called for each test. Oh, and you don't have to generate the test data if `data` is not an argument - move that check to the beginning.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, Thanks for your reply, actually test data creation is expensive and i was looking for a way to cache it somewhere(currently writing into a csv the results of the test data creation) .. but the problem is, only place i can place this segment of generating the test data is in pytest_generate_tests hook and it gets called 2 times because 2 test cases so stuck there.

Comment: Well, yes, that's why I proposed to cache it somewhere (outside of `pytest_generate_tests`, of course).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, the initialization is actually specific to calling test class ( i have added the details in the example above **sorry missed it before). As the calling test class is determined only at runtime, this initialization can be only placed inside pytest_generate_tests hook (or is there any other hook which can be used) ..

Comment: Obviously I wasn't clear enough, I put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the behavior of `pytest_generate_tests` is as expected, as it is called for each test. If you want to cache your test data, you can just add a cache outside of the hook, e.g. something like:

```py
testdata_cache = {}

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "data" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        class_name = metafunc.cls.__name__.split('_')[1]
        if class_name not in testdata_cache:
           // Initialize the test data based on the calling class
           testdata_cache[class_name] = //generated dictionary value with ids and test data
        test_data = testdata_cache[class_name]

        id_entity = [d['entity'] for d in test_data]
        metafunc.parametrize("data", test_data, ids=id_entity )
```

If you don't want to use a global variable, you could wrap this into a class, but this would be overkill in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, i think i get the gist of what you are saying and this can work.